# How to get accurate stars in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set up a "review" part in my app, where the user can select how many stars they want to rate on a scale of "1-5" including half stars. Everything is working fine in getting the amount of stars selected into my Firebase database, when it comes time to actually show the amount of stars that the user has selected, is where the trouble happens.

For example, if user A selected 3 stars and submits it, when it appears in my UITableViewCell it shows 3 stars... everything is good there.

If another user, lets say user B selected 4 stars and submits it, my UITableViewCell changes the stars that are shown in user A's review, so now it looks(*nothing in my firebase database changes it still reads it as a 4 star and 3 star rating*) as though there are two 4 star ratings.

If that wasn't clear, it's essentially like Yelp

This is the code that I tried:

```
let half = UIImage(named: "zeroPointFive")
let full = UIImage(named: "selectedReviewStar")

if let x = review?.ratingNumber?.floatValue{
                let number = String(x)
                someReviewStars.text = number

 //my attempt at using a switch to solve it

                switch x {
                case 0.50 : halfStar.image = half;print("we have a 0.5 here", x)

                case 1.0 : halfStar.image = full;print("we have a 1.0 here", x)
                default: return
            }


//I created different views for each star and added a subview image to them

  if someReviewStars.text == "0.0"{
                   someReviewStars.text = "No Stars"
                }


                if someReviewStars.text == "0.5"{
                   someReviewStars.text = ""
                    halfStar.image = half

                }

                if someReviewStars.text == "1.0"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                  halfStar.isHidden = true
                  oneStar.image = full


                }
                if someReviewStars.text == "1.5"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    halfStar.isHidden = true
                    oneStar.image = full
                    onePointFiveStar.image = half

                }


                if someReviewStars.text == "2.0"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    halfStar.isHidden = true
                    oneStar.image = full
                    onePointFiveStar.isHidden = true
                    twoStar.image = full
                }


                if someReviewStars.text == "2.5"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    let oneStarFrame = CGRect(x: -226, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let oneStarBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: oneStarFrame)
                    oneStarBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.oneStar.insertSubview(oneStarBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                    let twoStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -206, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17)
                    let twoStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoStarsFrame)
                    twoStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.twoStar.insertSubview(twoStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let twoPointFiveFrame = CGRect(x: -186, y: 0, width: 10, height: 17)
                    let twoPointFiveBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoPointFiveFrame)
                    twoPointFiveBackgroundImage.image = half

                    self.twoPointFiveStar.insertSubview(twoPointFiveBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                }



                if someReviewStars.text == "3.0"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    let oneStarFrame = CGRect(x: -226, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let oneStarBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: oneStarFrame)
                    oneStarBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.oneStar.insertSubview(oneStarBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                    let twoStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -206, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17)
                    let twoStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoStarsFrame)
                    twoStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.twoStar.insertSubview(twoStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let theframe = CGRect(x: -186, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    self.threeStar.image?.draw(in: theframe)
                    self.threeStar.image = full


                }
                if someReviewStars.text == "3.5"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    let oneStarFrame = CGRect(x: -226, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let oneStarBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: oneStarFrame)
                    oneStarBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.oneStar.insertSubview(oneStarBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                    let twoStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -206, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17)
                    let twoStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoStarsFrame)
                    twoStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.twoStar.insertSubview(twoStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let threeFrame = CGRect(x: -186, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let threeBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: threeFrame)
                    threeBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.threeStar.insertSubview(threeBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let threePointFiveFrame = CGRect(x: -167, y: 0, width: 10, height: 17)
                    let threePointFiveBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: threePointFiveFrame)
                    threePointFiveBackgroundImage.image = half

                    self.threePointFiveStar.insertSubview(threePointFiveBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                }
                if someReviewStars.text == "4.0"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    let oneStarFrame = CGRect(x: -226, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let oneStarBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: oneStarFrame)
                    oneStarBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.oneStar.insertSubview(oneStarBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                    let twoStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -206, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17)
                    let twoStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoStarsFrame)
                    twoStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.twoStar.insertSubview(twoStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let threeFrame = CGRect(x: -186, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let threeBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: threeFrame)
                    threeBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.threeStar.insertSubview(threeBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let fourStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -167, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let fourStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: fourStarsFrame)
                    fourStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.fourStar.insertSubview(fourStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                }
                if someReviewStars.text == "4.5"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    let oneStarFrame = CGRect(x: -226, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let oneStarBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: oneStarFrame)
                    oneStarBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.oneStar.insertSubview(oneStarBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                    let twoStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -206, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17)
                    let twoStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoStarsFrame)
                    twoStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.twoStar.insertSubview(twoStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let threeFrame = CGRect(x: -186, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let threeBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: threeFrame)
                    threeBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.threeStar.insertSubview(threeBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let fourStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -167, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let fourStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: fourStarsFrame)
                    fourStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.fourStar.insertSubview(fourStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let fourPointFiveFrame = CGRect(x: -146, y: 0, width: 10, height: 17)
                    let fourPointFiveBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: fourPointFiveFrame)
                    fourPointFiveBackgroundImage.image = half

                    self.fourPointFiveStar.insertSubview(fourPointFiveBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                }
                if someReviewStars.text == "5.0"{
                    someReviewStars.text = ""
                    let oneStarFrame = CGRect(x: -226, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let oneStarBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: oneStarFrame)
                    oneStarBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.oneStar.insertSubview(oneStarBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                    let twoStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -206, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17)
                    let twoStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: twoStarsFrame)
                    twoStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.twoStar.insertSubview(twoStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let threeFrame = CGRect(x: -186, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let threeBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: threeFrame)
                    threeBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.threeStar.insertSubview(threeBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let fourStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -167, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let fourStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: fourStarsFrame)
                    fourStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.fourStar.insertSubview(fourStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)

                    let fiveStarsFrame = CGRect(x: -146, y: 0, width: 19, height: 17)
                    let fiveStarsBackgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: fiveStarsFrame)
                    fiveStarsBackgroundImage.image = full

                    self.fiveStar.insertSubview(fiveStarsBackgroundImage, at: 0)


                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is inside of my tableView

```
class loadingTableReview: UITableViewController {


let cellId = "cellId"
var selectedUsersProfile:User?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    observeUserReviews()

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return reviews.count
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let review = reviews[indexPath.row]
     cell.review = review


    return cell
}


var reviews = [Reviews]()
var reviewDictionary = [String: Reviews]()



func observeUserReviews(){
    guard let uid = selectedUsersProfile?.id

        else{
    return
    }
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-reviews").child(uid)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in


        let reviewId = snapshot.key
        let messageReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("reviews").child(reviewId)

        messageReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as?[String: AnyObject]{
                let review = Reviews()
                review.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)


                if let fromId = review.fromId{
                    self.reviewDictionary[fromId] = review

                    self.reviews.append(review)
                    self.reviews.sort(by: { (review1, review2) -> Bool in
                        return (review1.timeStamp?.intValue)! > (review2.timeStamp?.intValue)!
                    })

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it has something more todo with how your tableview is pulling in the data than it does with the star rating. Maybe add the code showing how the data is displayed in your tableview.

Comment: @MwcsMac Thanks for the reply! I updated the answer how my tableView is handing everything

Comment: insertSubView/addView in a `UITableViewCell` which is reused, that maybe where your true issue lies.

Comment: @Larme Any suggestions on what else I can use besides insetSubView/addView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having 5 fixed imageviews in the cell and systematically setting their image property based on the rating value

for example:

```
 starImage1.image = rating < 0.5 ? nil : rating < 1 ? half : full
 starImage2.image = rating < 1.5 ? nil : rating < 2 ? half : full
 starImage3.image = rating < 2.5 ? nil : rating < 3 ? half : full
 starImage4.image = rating < 3.5 ? nil : rating < 4 ? half : full
 starImage5.image = rating < 4.5 ? nil : rating < 5 ? half : full
```